# StoredProcedures locks table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, locking

I have a Stored Procedure which takes some minutes for executing. This StoredProcedure does doing several selects, (batch-)updates and inserts on different tables.
Now, while this StoredProcedure is executing, the tables which are updated are locked. At the beginning of the stored procedure a bool-flag is switched from 1 to 0 and at the end the flag is switched from 0 to 1.
Now, other statements which are doing inserts or updates on this tables (which are updated from the StoredPRocedure) are locked during the StoredProcedure is executed (which results in a TimeOut-Exception).

Is there a way, that the StoredPRocedure does not locking any table? I have also tried the IsolationLevel ReadUncommited but the Problem still exists with this IsolationLevel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no quick answer to this.  You need to spend a bit of time studying [Locking in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172429%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).  And understand what transactions give you, what locks can and can't do, how long locks are held, isolation levels.

Once you have an improved understanding, you should be able to answer our won question, or at least ask a more focused question.